# Disabling/Removing HMR in webpack

Tags: gulp, webpack, webpack-hmr

Is there a way to remove the code for hot module replacement? I'm not even using it, have nothing in my config file telling webpack to generate it, and it's still generating code that's never ever going to fire anyway `if (false)`.

[image]

Can you disable the hot module stuff in webpack?

I'm using the gulp `webpack-stream` plugin, works great, however I'm sure there's something I'm missing to get this to work.